# How to fix dynamic sql query syntax error that shown in below in synapse?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('temp..#temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #temp
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    [CxID] int,
    [CompanyID] int,
    [Category] int -- this category column is created by ROW_NUMBER function over partition by [CxID] order by [CxID] and [CompanyID]
)

INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('1', '101', '1');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('1', '102', '2');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('1', '103', '3');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('2', '201', '1');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('3', '301', '1');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('4', '401', '1');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('5', '501', '1');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('5', '502', '2');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('5', '503', '3');
INSERT INTO #temp ([CxID], [CompanyID], [Number]) VALUES ('5', '504', '4');
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = (SELECT STRING_AGG(category,',') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM #temp WHERE category IS NOT NULL)t);

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select CxID
                    , CompanyID
                    , category
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(CompanyID)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);
```

Error Message: Parse error at line: 11, column: 34: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Question: We don't know the maximum number of CompanyID that customer can have in the historical data, and want to output like following:

| CxID | CompanyID1 | CompanyID2 | CompanyID3 | ... | CompanyIDx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 102 | 103 | ... | (NULL) |
| 2 | 201 | (NULL) | (NULL) | ... | (NULL) |
| 3 | 301 | (NULL) | (NULL) | ... | (NULL) |
| 4 | 401 | (NULL) | (NULL) | ... | (NULL) |
| 5 | 501 | 502 | 503 | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to avoid numbers as columns because pivot is bad with them.

But if you want then you have to change sql so it becomes like this:

```
SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4] from
```

instead of

```
SELECT 1,2,3,4 from
```